# Extracting data from specific cells for multiple files and display in a table POSH

Tags: excel, powershell

So I'am trying to write a PowerShell script to loop through Excel files in a directory the files all have different names. I am trying to have the script look in the file at specific cells and output them in the PowerShell window as a table. I also need the script to get the name of the file for example

```
Name           Column1            Column2           Column3
file1.xlsx     Yes                linux             extra info
file2.xlsx     no                 windows           more info
```

I have tried using `$value = $workbook.Item(2, 4)` and this works but I don't know how to loop between the files, format into a table and extract file name.

Edit:

```
$DirectoryPath = 'V:\directory goes here\

foreach ($File in (Get-ChildItem -Path $DirectoryPath))
{
#Do your work
$workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Open($File.FullName)
$workbook.sheets.item(1).activate()
$WorkbookTotal=$workbook.Worksheets.item(3)
$InternetFacingAnswer = $WorkbookTotal.Cells.Item(2, 4)
$OS = $WorkbookTotal.Cells.Item(4, 3)
$Guidance = $WorkbookTotal.Cells.Item(4,7)

$File.FullName
$File.Name
$InternetFacingAnswer.Text
$OS.Text
$Guidance.Text
$value | Format-Table -AutoSize
}
```

The current output i receive is:
V:\directory goes here\testfile.xlsx
testfile.xlsx
YES
Apples
Windows/Linux
addedinfo here

Application Creator Parent AddIndent Areas Borders Cells Column Columns ColumnWidth

---

Answer (score 1):

Might this commands help you with your task.

```
$DirectoryPath = 'C:\Temp\YourFiles'

foreach ($File in (Get-ChildItem -Path $DirectoryPath))
{
    #Do your work
    $File.FullName
    $File.Name
    $value | Format-Table -AutoSize
}
```

Hopefully I understand you right.
Your goal is to print the output to the powershell console right?
As I can see from your script you get the values you're looking for.
You could crate a hastable to collect all values and then print that as object to the console. So you should get a "nice" table.

```
[PSCustomObject[]]$Output = @() #Before foreach-loop

[System.Collections.Hashtable]$Hashtable = @{ #Inside foreach-loop
    Name = $File.Name
    Column1 = $InternetFacingAnswer.Text
    Column2 = $OS.Text
    Column3 = $Guidance.Text
}

$Output += New-Object -TypeName 'PSCustomObject' -Property $Hashtable



$Output  | Select-Object -Property Name, Column1, Column2, Column3 | Format-Table -AutoSize #After foreach-loop
```

See the example combined with your code snippet. Please add also your code and the errors if something does not work.

```
$DirectoryPath = 'V:\directory goes here\'

[PSCustomObject[]]$Output = @() #Before foreach-loop

foreach ($File in (Get-ChildItem -Path $DirectoryPath))
{
    #Do your work
    $workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Open($File.FullName)
    $workbook.sheets.item(1).activate()
    $WorkbookTotal=$workbook.Worksheets.item(3)
    $InternetFacingAnswer = $WorkbookTotal.Cells.Item(2, 4)
    $OS = $WorkbookTotal.Cells.Item(4, 3)
    $Guidance = $WorkbookTotal.Cells.Item(4,7)


    [System.Collections.Hashtable]$Hashtable = @{ #Inside foreach-loop
        Name = $File.Name
        Column1 = $InternetFacingAnswer.Text
        Column2 = $OS.Text
        Column3 = $Guidance.Text
    }

    $Output += New-Object -TypeName 'PSCustomObject' -Property $Hashtable

}

$Output  | Select-Object -Property Name, Column1, Column2, Column3 | Format-Table -AutoSize #After foreach-loop
```

Comment: I'm getting an error saying the file cannot be found but it is there? Also the data doesn't enter the table?

Comment: $DirectoryPath = 'V:\Example Directory\'

foreach ($File in (Get-ChildItem -Path $DirectoryPath))
{
    #Do your work
    $workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Open($File)
    $workbook.sheets.item(1).activate()
    $WorkbookTotal=$workbook.Worksheets.item(3)
    $InternetFacingAnswer = $WorkbookTotal.Cells.Item(2, 4)
    $OS = $WorkbookTotal.Cells.Item(4, 3)
    $Guidance = $WorkbookTotal.Cells.Item(4,7)

    $File.FullName
    $File.Name
    $InternetFacingAnswer.Text
    $OS.Text
    $Guidance.Text
    $value | Format-Table -AutoSize
}

Comment: please add the code to your initial post... but one thing i see: $excel.Workbooks.Open($File) <-- You need here the $File.FullName

Comment: Sorry first time posting! Script is now working however the output is not being added to the table it simply prints the output then some empty columns and moves on to the next one. Once finished it displays an empty table.

Comment: Code has been added.

Comment: is there still a problem / open question?

Comment: The output i receive is not in the table at all it simply places the information above the columns in a list. So i end up scrolling through PowerShell in order to read the output.

Comment: have you seen my edited answer with the second code block? Try to add that to your code. After that it should work as you wish.

Comment: I seem to now be getting a Null-valued expression or "InvokeMethodOnNull" error now. With or without your code.